# After signOutAndRemoveLocalData, reactive login?

Tags: ios, simperium

I am using the Simperium framework and are trying to todo a manual sign out with this method

```
- (void)signOutAndRemoveLocalData:(BOOL)remove
```

That works fine and the local data is deleted but now I would like the loginViewController to be "activated" again, how do I make that work? any idea?

Cheers
Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `authenticateIfNecessary` method on your Simperium object. If a user isn't currently signed in, this method should trigger the authentication interface to be displayed.